# grails when params list too long, some data are missing

Tags: grails, parameter-passing

I have a controller that inserts cities in a country.
Everything works fine, until the list becomes too long, that the data are simply ignored.

In debugging this is what i find:

```
println "0-" + params
def instance = Country.get(params.id)
instance.properties = params
println "1-" + instance.areas
println "2-" + instance.areas.size()
```

println params shows correctly all the areas.

println instance.areas misses the new area

println instance.areas.size() shows the old number of size.

If for a country the number of  areas is small, everything works correctly.

Thanks

Comment: How many items is too many? Are you talking about like 500, 50,000 or what? The behavior you are describing surprises me. If you can show enough code to be able to reproduce the problem I will be happy to take a look.

Comment: Is 255 the limit you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you are running into the limit that the data binder imposes on how large it will automatically grow a collection.  The default is 256.  You can change this value by setting `grails.databinding.autoGrowCollectionLimit` to a higher number in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`.

See the "Data Binding and Many-ended Associations" section under http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding which describes this property.

**EDIT (to address question left in a comment below):**

> Hi Jeff, I am trying to submit a huge number of params list, I'm
> getting 9842 params to contraoller where are missing some params. How
> can solve it. Grails: 2.3.8

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/asifbindinglimit.

[grails-app/controllers/asifbindinglimit/DemoController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asifbindinglimit/blob/45df422a25884e4725200b0c4202bd3dc1b137f9/grails-app/controllers/asifbindinglimit/DemoController.groovy)

```
package asifbindinglimit

import grails.converters.JSON

class DemoController {

    def createWidget(Widget w) {
        render w as JSON
    }
}

class Widget {
    List<String> names
}
```

[grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L123](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asifbindinglimit/blob/45df422a25884e4725200b0c4202bd3dc1b137f9/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L123)

```
grails.databinding.autoGrowCollectionLimit = 10_000
```

[grails-app/controllers/asifbindinglimit/DemoController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/asifbindinglimit/blob/45df422a25884e4725200b0c4202bd3dc1b137f9/grails-app/controllers/asifbindinglimit/DemoController.groovy)

```
package asifbindinglimit

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test parameter binding"() {
        given:
        9482.times {
            params."names[${it}]" = "Value ${it}"
        }

        when:
        controller.createWidget()

        then:
        response.json.names.size() == 9482
        response.json.names[0] == 'Value 0'
        response.json.names[1] == 'Value 1'
        response.json.names[2] == 'Value 2'
        response.json.names[9479] == 'Value 9479'
        response.json.names[9480] == 'Value 9480'
        response.json.names[9481] == 'Value 9481'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am trying to submit a huge number of params list, I'm getting 9842 params to contraoller where are missing some params. How can solve it. 
Grails: 2.3.8

Comment: @Asif I created a sample app which demonstrates how to support that.  See updated info I added in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, for your response!  
I've added `grails.databinding.autoGrowCollectionLimit = 20_000` 
I checked DOM, DOM is generating about 10216 params but when I submit (form submit) it then still I get 9845 params in the controller

Comment: If you can send a PR to my repo that demonstrates a problematic scenario I will be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: What is 10_000? Why underscore? is there any documentation related to this number?